# Camel with Blueprint - Marshalling exception - Jackson Library (Data format 'json-jackson' could not be created))

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse

I use **JBoss Fuse (jboss-fuse-6.1.0.redhat-379)** which has predefined bundles installed with Camel features of Redhat.

As per recommendation, we opted for Blueprint DSL for configuration. I have configuration as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint"
    xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf" xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.1.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
        http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd">

    <cm:property-placeholder persistent-id="serviceUrlPlaceHolder"
        update-strategy="reload">
        <cm:default-properties>
            <cm:property name="CXFserver" value="http://localhost:8183/" />
            <cm:property name="service" value="copi" />
        </cm:default-properties>
    </cm:property-placeholder>


    <cxf:rsServer id="rsServer" address="http://localhost:8183/copi"
        serviceClass="com.karthik.services.InboxRestService"
        loggingFeatureEnabled="true" />

    <cxf:rsServer id="rsServerDup" address="http://localhost:8183/copi2"
        serviceClass="com.karthik.services.InboxRestService"
        loggingFeatureEnabled="true" />

    <camelContext id="inboxServiceRouterContext"
        xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
        <route id="inboxRoute">
            <from uri="cxfrs:bean:rsServer?bindingStyle=SimpleConsumer" />
            <to uri="direct:inboxService" />
        </route>
        <route id="inboxRouteDup">
            <from uri="cxfrs:bean:rsServerDup" />
            <to uri="direct:inboxService" />
        </route>
        <route id="inboxServiceRoute">
            <from uri="direct:inboxService" />
            <to uri="bean:inboxService?method=updateCompletedTask" />
            <marshal ref="jsonDataformat" />
        </route>
    </camelContext>


    <bean id="inboxService" class="com.karthik.services.InboxService" />
    <bean id="jsonDataformat" class="org.apache.camel.model.dataformat.JsonDataFormat">
        <property name="unmarshalType" value="com.karthik.bo.Task" />
        <property name="library" value="Jackson"></property>
    </bean>

</blueprint>
```

Please note that I have Jackson library added.
On installation of my feature, I get following exception.

```
Failed to create route inboxServiceRoute at: >>> Marshal[ref:jsonDataformat] <<< in route: Route(inboxServiceRoute)[[From[direct:inboxService]] -> [To[... because of Data format 'json-jackson' could not be created. Ensure that the data format is valid and the associated Camel component is present on the classpath
```

I have the following dependencies defined in my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.karthik</groupId>
    <artifactId>inboxServiceRouter</artifactId>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>Inbox ServiceRouter Camel Spring-CXF Route</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <camel.cxf.redhat.v>2.12.0.redhat-610379</camel.cxf.redhat.v>
        <jackson.version>1.8.6</jackson.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0.redhat-610379</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.cxf.redhat.v}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.cxf.redhat.v}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-cxf-transport</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.cxf.redhat.v}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-cxf</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.cxf.redhat.v}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <!-- use the same version as your Camel core version -->
        </dependency>


        <!-- logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.cxf.redhat.v}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.apache.camel.example.cxf.CamelRouteClient</mainClass>
                    <includePluginDependencies>false</includePluginDependencies>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <property>
                            <key>java.util.logging.config.file</key>
                            <value>logging.properties</value>
                        </property>
                    </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- allows the route to be ran via 'mvn camel:run' -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                <artifactId>camel-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.14.0</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <!-- <Require-Bundle>org.apache.cxf.bundle</Require-Bundle> -->
                        <Import-Package>
                            org.apache.camel.spring,org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl,*
                        </Import-Package>
                    </instructions>

                </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-artifacts</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifacts>
                                <artifact>
                                    <file>target/classes/features.xml</file>
                                    <type>xml</type>
                                    <classifier>features</classifier>
                                </artifact>
                            </artifacts>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

How do I resolve this? The irony is, this worked for sometime and started complaining all of sudden..

Comment: Just to be sure you have done a features:install camel-jackson, and its installed and started if you run a `list` command in the shell ?

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Claus lbsen Yes. I installed the feature camel-jackson and I also included the feature in features.xml along with the other bundles.  I have a question - I have jackson-core-asl, jackson-mapper-asl etc for this dataformats referring to [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21578584/exception-using-jackson-json-library-with-camel). Or is the feature itself is sufficient for the purpose?

Comment: @ClausIbsen - I believe its with the feature camel-jackson. Currently it works and I'm not sure why this suddenly stops. I had to delete the data folder and had to install all again which now works. Kindly let me know for the query posted in above comment on the dependencies for data-format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have to agree with **@Claus Ibsen** comment on **feature install of *camel-jackson***. Though I had already installed, something wasn't right with jBoss Fuse. I had to delete the 'data' folder and had to do the installation. I haven't faced any problem as of now. So, I guess this should be it.

Thank you @Claus Ibsen.